# Tbody data showing "None" when scraped?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Last time I ran into this issue, adding the Header info fixed -- doesn't seem to be the case here.  Trying different methods, but ultimately my goal is to scrape the info from all of the tables on each of the links listed.

It's coming up as tbody data -- specifically class: table-responsive.xs (I think).

I've tried taking all of the tbody data, and also just this class, but I'm not getting any result except a list of "none" values.

Is there another approach? I hoped adding the Header in was the solution, but doesn't seem to be.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
profiles = []
session = HTMLSession()

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = [
    'https://magicseaweed.com/New-Jersey-Monmouth-County-Surfing/277/',
    'https://magicseaweed.com/New-Jersey-Ocean-City-Surfing/279/'
]
for url in urls:
    r = session.get(url)
    # wait for 3s until the page fully loaded
    r.html.render(sleep=3, timeout=20)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.raw_html, "html.parser")
    for profile in soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "table-responsive.xs"}):
        profiles.append(profile)
for p in profiles:
    print(p)
```

Also tried:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
profiles = []
session = HTMLSession()

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = [
    'https://magicseaweed.com/New-Jersey-Monmouth-County-Surfing/277/',
    'https://magicseaweed.com/New-Jersey-Ocean-City-Surfing/279/'
]
for url in urls:
    r = session.get(url)
    # wait for 3s until the page fully loaded
    r.html.render(sleep=3, timeout=20)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.raw_html, "html.parser")
    for profile in soup.find_all('a'):
        profile = profile.get('tbody')
        profiles.append(profile)
for p in profiles:
    print(p)
```

Lastly -

With someone's great guidance here, I am separately able to pull the full json data with this script below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json


r = requests.get('https://magicseaweed.com/api/mdkey/spot?&limit=-1')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()).to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)


print(df)
```

However, being that I live in NJ, I only really care about the NJ waves.  I used an HREF scrape to get the URLs I'd like to see data for.  Ideally, I could pull a week's worth of info, but if the day is the only possible option, I'll survive.

I tried including an if statement that only focuses on specific URLs (it is in the JSON data), but not having luck.  Ultimately I want to add an OR to include all of the links listed, unless someone has a better idea?

I know I could easily match them once extracted, but I don't want to run 9,000 rows every time, when I only need a select few.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json


r = requests.get('https://magicseaweed.com/api/mdkey/spot?&limit=-1')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()).to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)

for d in df:
    if d and '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683' in df:
        print(d)


# '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683'
# '/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/'
# '/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/'
# '/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/'
# '/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/'
# '/Bay-Head-Surf-Report/4951/'
# '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/'
# '/Boardwalk-Surf-Report/9183/'
# '/Bradley-Beach-Surf-Report/7944/'
# '/Casino-Surf-Report/9175/'
# '/Deal-Surf-Report/822/'
# '/Dog-Park-Surf-Report/9174/'
# '/Jenkinsons-Surf-Report/4053/'
# '/Long-Branch-Surf-Report/7946/'
# '/Long-Branch-Surf-Report/7947/'
# '/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/'
# '/Monmouth-Beach-Surf-Report/4055/'
# '/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/'
# '/Point-Pleasant-Surf-Report/7942/'
# '/Sea-Girt-Surf-Report/7943/'
# '/Spring-Lake-Surf-Report/7941/'
# '/The-Cove-Surf-Report/385/'
# '/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/'
# '/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/'
# '/Deal-Surf-Report/822/'
# '/North-Street-Surf-Report/4946/'
# '/Margate-Pier-Surf-Report/4054/'
# '/Ocean-City-NJ-Surf-Report/391/'
# '/7th-St-Surf-Report/7918/'
# '/Brigantine-Surf-Report/4747/'
# '/Brigantine-Seawall-Surf-Report/4942/'
# '/Crystals-Surf-Report/4943/'
# '/Longport-32nd-St-Surf-Report/1158/'
# '/Margate-Pier-Surf-Report/4054/'
# '/North-Street-Surf-Report/4946/'
# '/Ocean-City-NJ-Surf-Report/391/'
# '/South-Carolina-Ave-Surf-Report/4944/'
# '/St-James-Surf-Report/7917/'
# '/States-Avenue-Surf-Report/390/'
# '/Ventnor-Pier-Surf-Report/4945/'
# '/14th-Street-Surf-Report/9055/'
# '/18th-St-Surf-Report/9056/'
# '/30th-St-Surf-Report/9057/'
# '/56th-St-Surf-Report/9059/'
# '/Diamond-Beach-Surf-Report/9061/'
# '/Strathmere-Surf-Report/7919/'
# '/The-Cove-Surf-Report/7921/'
# '/14th-Street-Surf-Report/9055/'
# '/18th-St-Surf-Report/9056/'
# '/30th-St-Surf-Report/9057/'
# '/56th-St-Surf-Report/9059/'
# '/Avalon-Surf-Report/821/'
# '/Diamond-Beach-Surf-Report/9061/'
# '/Nuns-Beach-Surf-Report/7948/'
# '/Poverty-Beach-Surf-Report/4056/'
# '/Sea-Isle-City-Surf-Report/1281/'
# '/Stockton-Surf-Report/393/'
# '/Stone-Harbor-Surf-Report/7920/'
# '/Strathmere-Surf-Report/7919/'
# '/The-Cove-Surf-Report/7921/'
# '/Wildwood-Surf-Report/392/'

//or can use the SurfIDs:

3683
386
7945
857
4050
4951
3683
9183
7944
9175
822
9174
4053
7946
7947
386
4055
7945
7942
7943
7941
385
3683
4050
822
4946
4054
391
7918
4747
4942
4943
1158
4054
4946
391
4944
7917
390
4945
9055
9056
9057
9059
9061
7919
7921
9055
9056
9057
9059
821
9061
7948
4056
1281
393
7920
7919
7921
392
```

Comment: Most of the site is behind JavaScript. The layout might have also changed. What exactly are you trying to scrape?

Comment: You asked this question previously and I responded to it: you can pull all the info from that website in a big table, which contains all the info those individual tables have. You can further dissect that json response or dataframe, and have all data with a single network call.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire thanks - I am using your fix as well, it's amazing.  I was hoping to get the whole week outlook for only specific cities (I can narrow them down on the CSV output from the Json), but it looks like it's only the day's information.  I was hoping to pull all of the tables from each of these pages (the individual cities)

Comment: @baduker I'm looking to get the wave sizes and details from all of the tables on each link.  Is that not possible because of their structure?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire I'm going to edit my code now to ask a more specific question - apologies

Comment: @AnthonyMadle your question seems fine to me. It's just that I had a brief look (again) at that page, and couldn't find multiple tables on it. Also unsure where weekly weather data would be in page, or what api address is being XHRed for it.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire got it - it's confusing, but specific locations like this URL have a daily forecast if you scroll down: https://magicseaweed.com/14th-Street-Surf-Report/9055/

I'm constantly looking for NJ spots to drive to and surf on a weekly basis LOL so having more than a day's data is very valuable.  I edited my question to take a different approach if a week's info isn't possible, a little confused though.

Comment: In the big table (previous question) there is a column `surfAreaId`. What are the IDs for NJ, and can you filter the big dataframe for those?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire the IDs are the end of the URLs in the code, so I could get those easily by splitting in Excel.  Ultimately I think it's the same concept though of only returning the dataset if one of the columns matches the info provided? for instance, instead of putting in the URLs like I did, I could put in those IDs, but is there a way to map it to the JSON, so it only pulls those lines? Rather than doing it after scraping all the data?

Comment: What are the SurfIDs for NJ? Do you know them? How many are they? it's trivial to filter a pandas dataframe by them. Failing that, could you filter the dataframe by lat/lon?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire ahhh I see - I can get them easily by splitting the URLs, but they are not in sequential order.  I have a list of them, is there any way I could add the list of IDs in the script, and make it so the code only runs for those IDs? I'm more of an Excel person venturing into this, it makes sense in my head there, but hard to execute there.

Comment: So do you have a list of NJ surfIds?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire added them into my script - those are the IDs I'm looking to scrape daily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Given you confirmed your links list (and they remain static, do not change), you can check all of them daily like this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


id_list = [
'/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683',
'/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/',
'/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/',
'/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/',
'/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/',
'/Bay-Head-Surf-Report/4951/',
'/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/',
'/Boardwalk-Surf-Report/9183/',
'/Bradley-Beach-Surf-Report/7944/',
'/Casino-Surf-Report/9175/',
'/Deal-Surf-Report/822/',
'/Dog-Park-Surf-Report/9174/',
'/Jenkinsons-Surf-Report/4053/',
'/Long-Branch-Surf-Report/7946/',
'/Long-Branch-Surf-Report/7947/',
'/Manasquan-Surf-Report/386/',
'/Monmouth-Beach-Surf-Report/4055/',
'/Ocean-Grove-Surf-Report/7945/',
'/Point-Pleasant-Surf-Report/7942/',
'/Sea-Girt-Surf-Report/7943/',
'/Spring-Lake-Surf-Report/7941/',
'/The-Cove-Surf-Report/385/',
'/Belmar-Surf-Report/3683/',
'/Avon-Surf-Report/4050/',
'/Deal-Surf-Report/822/',
'/North-Street-Surf-Report/4946/',
'/Margate-Pier-Surf-Report/4054/',
'/Ocean-City-NJ-Surf-Report/391/',
'/7th-St-Surf-Report/7918/',
'/Brigantine-Surf-Report/4747/',
'/Brigantine-Seawall-Surf-Report/4942/',
'/Crystals-Surf-Report/4943/',
'/Longport-32nd-St-Surf-Report/1158/',
'/Margate-Pier-Surf-Report/4054/',
'/North-Street-Surf-Report/4946/',
'/Ocean-City-NJ-Surf-Report/391/',
'/South-Carolina-Ave-Surf-Report/4944/',
'/St-James-Surf-Report/7917/',
'/States-Avenue-Surf-Report/390/',
'/Ventnor-Pier-Surf-Report/4945/',
'/14th-Street-Surf-Report/9055/',
'/18th-St-Surf-Report/9056/',
'/30th-St-Surf-Report/9057/',
'/56th-St-Surf-Report/9059/',
'/Diamond-Beach-Surf-Report/9061/',
'/Strathmere-Surf-Report/7919/',
'/The-Cove-Surf-Report/7921/',
'/14th-Street-Surf-Report/9055/',
'/18th-St-Surf-Report/9056/',
'/30th-St-Surf-Report/9057/',
'/56th-St-Surf-Report/9059/',
'/Avalon-Surf-Report/821/',
'/Diamond-Beach-Surf-Report/9061/',
'/Nuns-Beach-Surf-Report/7948/',
'/Poverty-Beach-Surf-Report/4056/',
'/Sea-Isle-City-Surf-Report/1281/',
'/Stockton-Surf-Report/393/',
'/Stone-Harbor-Surf-Report/7920/',
'/Strathmere-Surf-Report/7919/',
'/The-Cove-Surf-Report/7921/',
'/Wildwood-Surf-Report/392/'
]

headers = {

'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

for x in id_list:

    url = 'https://magicseaweed.com' + x

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        dfs = pd.read_html(str(soup))
        for df in dfs:
            print(df)
            if df.shape[0] > 50:
                df.to_csv(f"{x.replace('/', '_').replace('-', '_')}.csv")
            print('____________')
    except Exception as e:
        print(x, e)
```

This return several dataframes for each page, some more, some less, and saves the ones with more than 50 rows:

```
    0   1   2
0   Low     12:24AM     -0.05m
1   High    6:25AM  1.28m
2   Low     12:28PM     -0.01m
3   High    6:49PM  1.66m

____________

    0   1
0   First Light     5:36AM
1   Sunrise     6:05AM
2   Sunset  8:00PM
3   Last Light  8:30PM

____________

    Unnamed: 0  Surf    Swell Rating    Primary Swell   Primary Swell.1     Primary Swell.2     Secondary Swell     Secondary Swell.1   Secondary Swell.2   Secondary Swell.3   ...     Wind    Wind.1  Weather     Weather.1   Prob.   Unnamed: 17     Unnamed: 18     Unnamed: 19     Unnamed: 20     Unnamed: 21
0   Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     ...     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08     Wednesday 10/08
1   12am    0.5-0.8m    NaN     0.9m    6s  NaN     0.5m    9s  NaN     NaN     ...     11 11 kph   NaN     NaN     26°c    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   3am     0.3-0.5m    NaN     0.5m    9s  NaN     0.8m    6s  NaN     NaN     ...     13 17 kph   NaN     NaN     24°c    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   6am     0.2-0.3m    NaN     0.5m    9s  NaN     0.7m    6s  NaN     NaN     ...     12 16 kph   NaN     NaN     24°c    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   9am     0.3-0.6m    NaN     0.5m    9s  NaN     0.7m    6s  NaN     NaN     ...     13 16 kph   NaN     NaN     25°c    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
121     High    11:57PM     1.34m   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
122     First Light     5:42AM  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
123     Sunrise     6:10AM  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
124     Sunset  7:53PM  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
125     Last Light  8:21PM  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN

126 rows × 22 columns

____________

    0   1   2
0   Low     12:24AM     -0.05m
1   High    6:25AM  1.28m
2   Low     12:28PM     -0.01m
3   High    6:49PM  1.66m

____________

    0   1
0   First Light     5:36AM
1   Sunrise     6:05AM
2   Sunset  8:00PM
3   Last Light  8:30PM

____________

    0   1   2
0   Low     1:19AM  -0.13m
1   High    7:21AM  1.37m
2   Low     1:26PM  -0.06m
3   High    7:43PM  1.7m

____________

    0   1
0   First Light     5:37AM
1   Sunrise     6:06AM
2   Sunset  7:59PM
3   Last Light  8:28PM

____________

    0   1   2
0   Low     2:11AM  -0.18m
1   High    8:14AM  1.43m
2   Low     2:21PM  -0.09m
3   High    8:34PM  1.69m

____________

    0   1
0   First Light     5:38AM
1   Sunrise     6:07AM
2   Sunset  7:58PM
3   Last Light  8:27PM

____________

    0   1   2
0   Low     2:59AM  -0.21m
1   High    9:05AM  1.47m
2   Low     3:13PM  -0.09m
3   High    9:24PM  1.64m

____________

    0   1
0   First Light     5:39AM
1   Sunrise     6:08AM
2   Sunset  7:57PM
3   Last Light  8:25PM

____________

    0   1   2
0   Low     3:46AM  -0.2m
1   High    9:57AM  1.47m
2   Low     4:03PM  -0.06m
3   High    10:14PM     1.56m

____________

    0   1
0   First Light     5:40AM
1   Sunrise     6:09AM
2   Sunset  7:55PM
3   Last Light  8:24PM

____________

    0   1   2
0   Low     4:29AM  -0.15m
1   High    10:48AM     1.46m
2   Low     4:52PM  0.01m
3   High    11:05PM     1.46m

____________

    0   1
0   First Light     5:41AM
1   Sunrise     6:10AM
2   Sunset  7:54PM
3   Last Light  8:23PM

____________

    0   1   2
0   Low     5:12AM  -0.07m
1   High    11:39AM     1.43m
2   Low     5:42PM  0.1m
3   High    11:57PM     1.34m

____________

    0   1
0   First Light     5:42AM
1   Sunrise     6:10AM
2   Sunset  7:53PM
3   Last Light  8:21PM
```

Comment: This is the code I'm looking for! I'm getting a "display is not defined" on the word display though??

Comment: Replace display with `print`... give me a moment, will update based on your ID list.

Comment: Amazing @platipus_on_fire - I'm going to push it to a CSV for now until linking directly to a G Sheet.  This is amazing, beyond excited to have this visibility.  Surf is most definitely up!

Comment: don't want to bug you with questions, I thought adding ".to_csv('NJWaves', index=False)" after the dfs variable line would create a file? Would you advise adding elsewhere to get it working - my apologies, I don't entirely understand where to place it

Comment: Updated my answer. `dfs` is a list of all datafrrames (tables) on that page. You may want to choose which dataframe you need, and save that to csv. You can use some condition based on dataframe column name content, or the length of the dataframe, etc. And then you  can save that particular dataframe to file.

Comment: can't thank you enough. I'm going to tweak so it creates one CSV, but I should be able to handle that. I learned it just need to go through my notes.  Learned so much from you - major kudos!

Comment: just curious, so I tried updating the script so that all of the links return in one CSV (not individual ones).. I think I did this in the cleanest way possible.  The return isn't as clean as I hoped, which is fine (I guess it's because of the tables, not like how it looks from the other JSON method).  My only question, is it possible to print the URL next to every cell where the value comes from? I adjusted to print(url, df), but can't seem to get a clean output with the source link.  A little confused why that wouldn't work?

Comment: You would probably need to add another column to each individual dataframe, prior to merging them. At this point, you would probably need to go through a (relatively short) tutorial on pandas: there are quite a few on Youtube for example, and you would be soon up-and-running with pandas fundamentals.